# Using `\hyperref` inside Tikz (forest)

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, forest

Here's my cute little forest:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    [Link to Country 
      [Link to United States]
      [Link to United Kingdom]
    ]
  \end{forest}

  \section{Country}
  \label{sec:country}
  \subsection{United States}
  \label{sec:country:us}
  \subsection{United Kingdom}
  \label{sec:country:ul}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to `\hyperref` the forest's leaves to the corresponding section and subsections, such that when you click on *Link to Country* you'll get directed to the section *Country* and so forth. This is what I have tried:

```
...
\begin{forest}
  [\hyperref[sec:country]{Link to Country}
    [\hyperref[sec:country:us]{Link to United States}]
    [\hyperref[sec:country:uk]{Link to United Kingdom}]
  ]
\end{forest}
...
```

Unfortunately I got a bunch of errors and the code didn't produce anything. My guess is that the macro `hyperref` expands into something that breaks either Tikz or `forest`'s syntax. But I don't know much about Latex to find the solution myself.

When I use `hyperref` outside of the forest, it works fine. So obviously no problem with the packages.

`\ref{...}` appears to work fine so obviously it must be possible to have link inside a Tikz/forest.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have just to make the optional argument to `\hyperref` “invisible” to `forest`: use braces.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [{\hyperref[sec:country]{Link to Country}}
    [{\hyperref[sec:country:us]{Link to United States}}]
    [{\hyperref[sec:country:uk]{Link to United Kingdom}}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\section{Country}
\label{sec:country}
\subsection{United States}
\label{sec:country:us}
\subsection{United Kingdom}
\label{sec:country:uk}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a convenience wrapper based on [egreg's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347815/) which makes the tree specification a bit less cumbersome.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\forestset{
  declare toks={country link}{},
  declare toks={country link label}{},
  country links/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      where content={}{}{
        split option={content}{|}{country link,country link label},
        delay={
          content/.process={OOw2}{country link}{country link label}{\hyperref[sec:##1]{##2}},
        }
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  country links
  [country|Link to Country
    [country:us|Link to United States]
    [country:uk|Link to United Kingdom]
  ]
\end{forest}
\section{Country}
\label{sec:country}
\subsection{United States}
\label{sec:country:us}
\subsection{United Kingdom}
\label{sec:country:uk}
\end{document}
```

[image: country links]